# Scala: How to get the result of a Future

Tags: scala, future

I've a method that returns a `Future` like this...

```
def isTokenExpired(token: String): Future[Boolean] = {
  ...
}
```

... and then I've another method that invokes `isTokenExpired` that returns a `Boolean` like this:

```
def isExpired(token: String): Boolean = {
  var result = true
  isTokenExpired(token).onComplete {
    case Success(r) => result = r
    case Failure(_) => result = true
  }
  result
}
```

Is there a better way to write the `isExpired` method?

**EDIT**

As requested by EECOLOR, let me provide you with more details. For my Play application I've implemented an authorization mechanism based on JSON Web Token (jwt). All the claims are contained in the jwt except the expiration time, which is stored in a MongoDB collection. Here below is a summary of how my `Token` class looks like:

```
class Token {
  ...

  def id: String = { ... }
  def issueTime: LocalDateTime = { ... }
  def issuer: String = { ... }
  ...
  def isValid: Boolean = { ... }
  def isExpired: Boolean = { /* uses ReactiveMongo to access MongoDB  */ }
}
```

As you can see, all the jwt properties are self-contained except expiration info. Method `isExpired` uses ReactiveMongo, which always returns a `Future`. To make things even more complex, I use this jwt in a customized `Action` like this:

```
class SecuredAction[T <: Controller] private(private val methodName: String)
  extends ActionBuilder[ApiRequest] {

  ...

  def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (ApiRequest[A]) => Future[SimpleResult]) = {{
    request.headers.get(HeaderNames.AUTHORIZATION) match {
      case Some(header) => s"""$AuthType (.*)""".r.unapplySeq(header).map(_.head.trim)
      case _ => None
    }} match {
      case Some(tokenString) => {
        val token = Token(tokenString)

        if (!token.isValid) {
          Logger.warn(s"request ${request.uri} not authorized: token ${token.id} has been tampered")
          Future.successful(Unauthorized(AuthErrors.authenticationViolated(token.subject)(request).asJson))
        } else if (token.isExpired) {
          Logger.debug(s"request ${request.uri} not authorized: token ${token.id} has expired")
          Future.successful(Unauthorized(AuthErrors.authenticationExpired(token.subject)(request).asJson))
        } else if (!isAuthorized(token)) {
          Logger.info(s"request ${request.uri} not authorized: required claims not defined for account ${token.subject}")
          Future.successful(Forbidden(AuthErrors.requestNotAuthorized(token.subject)(request).asJson))
        } else {
          Logger.debug(s"request ${request.uri} authorized for account ${token.subject}")
          block(new ApiRequest(token, request))
        }
      }
      case _ => {
        Logger.debug(s"request ${request.uri} not authenticated")
        Future.successful(Unauthorized(
          AuthErrors.requestNotAuthenticated()(request).asJson
        ).withHeaders(HeaderNames.WWW_AUTHENTICATE -> AuthType))
      }
    }
  }
```

As you can see, I need to return a `Future[play.mvc.results.Result]`, not a `Future[Boolean]`as would return `isExpired` if I used `Future.map`. Do you get to point?

Comment: To give you a better advise we would need to know the context in which you are using this code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function you wrote will not work as you would think. It would (likely) first return `true` and later set the `result` variable.

Normally you would do something like this:

```
isTokenExpired(token).map { result =>
   // do stuff
}
```

In a framework like Play you would map the `Future` to an http response and give Play back a `Future[SimpleResult]`. Play knows how to handle `Future` results.

In general it's recommended you do not wait for a `Future` to complete in production code, but work with the values in the `Future` and let the framework you are using handle the result.

In tests it might come in handy to wait for a result, you can do that like this:

```
Await.result(someFuture, 5.seconds)
```

**Edit**

I would probably extract the construction of a token so that I end up with a `Future[Token]`. That allows me to more easily compose things. It also allows me to create code that has a better architecture and is easier to test.

I would probably break down the code into more smaller methods, but the example below gives you an idea of the direction I would take.

```
class TokenService(connection: MongoConnection) {

  def tokenFor(tokenString: String): Future[Token] = ???
}

class SecuredAction(tokenService: TokenService) extends 
  ActionBuilder[ApiRequest] {

  import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits._

  def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (ApiRequest[A]) => Future[SimpleResult]) =
    extractTokenFrom(request) match {
      case Some(tokenString) => {

        tokenService.tokenFor(tokenString) flatMap {
          case token if (!token.isValid) =>
            Logger.warn(s"request ${request.uri} not authorized: token ${token.id} has been tampered")
            Future.successful(Unauthorized(AuthErrors.authenticationViolated(token.subject)(request).asJson))
          case token if (token.isExpired) =>
            Logger.debug(s"request ${request.uri} not authorized: token ${token.id} has expired")
            Future.successful(Unauthorized(AuthErrors.authenticationExpired(token.subject)(request).asJson))
          case token if (!token.isAuthorized) =>
            Logger.info(s"request ${request.uri} not authorized: required claims not defined for account ${token.subject}")
            Future.successful(Forbidden(AuthErrors.requestNotAuthorized(token.subject)(request).asJson))
          case token =>
            Logger.debug(s"request ${request.uri} authorized for account ${token.subject}")
            block(new ApiRequest(token, request))
        }
      }
      case _ =>
        Logger.debug(s"request ${request.uri} not authenticated")
        Future.successful(Unauthorized(
          AuthErrors.requestNotAuthenticated()(request).asJson).withHeaders(HeaderNames.WWW_AUTHENTICATE -> AuthType))
    }

  val AuthType = "MyAuthType"
  val TokenHeader = s"""$AuthType (.*)""".r

  def extractTokenFrom(request: RequestHeader) = {
    val authorizationHeader = request.headers.get(HeaderNames.AUTHORIZATION)
    authorizationHeader flatMap {
      case TokenHeader(token) => Some(token.trim)
      case _ => None
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes... I know... but in my case I need a Boolean, not a Future[Boolean]. Is Await.result so bad in production code?

Comment: Using `Await.result` or its cousin `Await.ready` in production code is likely to lead to deadlocks.

Comment: I've just added more info to my post so that you can understand why I need a Boolean instead of a Future[Boolean]. Thanks.

Comment: OK, I see and just confirm my vote to your answer ;-) Thanks a lot.

Comment: Await.result(someFuture, 5.seconds)  should be Await.result(someFuture, 5 seconds)   without the "DOT" between 5 and seconds. and also need to import  import scala.concurrent.duration._

Comment: @temple You are right about the import. I would however recommend against the use of postfix operators. They require you to import that language feature and can cause tricky problems in certain situations.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to make future current by *literally* waiting for the result forever:

```
Await.result(futureResult, Duration.Inf)
```

Waiting forever transforms a `Future[Value]` into a `Value` which is what you want.

That's how I love to comment this move in my code...

```
// wait forever to make future current (?)
```

**Obs.** I infinite duration *only* in my ScalaTest. For production, the waiting period should be tuned as done by [@EECOLOR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22900324/3504561).

Comment: and I love to comment such code as `// this is how deadlocks are born`

Comment: You can tune it as @EECOLOR did but then it gets less suspense.

Comment: @om-nom-nom I have edited my answer. Thank you for your note which brought me back to reality.

Comment: @Ryan. What's wrong in using `Await.result` in a ScalaTest `FunSuite`? @EECOLOR sees it as handy.

Comment: @user3504561 You should never use `Await.result` in production code. Especially in web frameworks, this quickly fills up the thread pool. On top of that, it opens up the possibility for the elusive deadlock problem. This is a state where one side is waiting for the other side to finish waiting. As I stated in my answer, it's fine to use in a test suite, because generally you are using it only to extract and test the result.

Comment: Iam not sure if Await.result is the right way to do it