# how to access and merge the multiple DataFrame of Future types in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, parallel-processing, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I have spark scala application. I am trying to use Futures inside it to parallelize the few independent sets of operations. I am calling them in a Futures and they are returning me DataFrame of Future types How can I merge them at the end and throw an error if any of the Future fails to compute. Below is my code. When I try to apply the union of Dataframe in onComplete block it says this error

```
value union is not a member of scala.concurrent.Future[(scala.concurrent.Future[org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame], scala.concurrent.Future[org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame], scala.concurrent.Future[org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame])]..
```

Any help would be highly appreciated Thanks

```
val future_session = Future{ ProcessSession(df, spark) }
val future_links =  Future{ ProcessSession(df, spark) }
val future_nodes = Future { ProcessSession(df, spark) }

val result = for {
      r1 <- future_session
      r2 <- future_links
      r3 <- future_nodes
} yield ( 
   r1,r2,r3
)

result.onComplete {          
    case Success(x) => {
      log.info("Execution completed")       
    }
    case Failure(e) => e.printStackTrace
}
```

Comment: You can unpack the DF from the Futures result and do `.union()` on all the results set.

Comment: Thanks Sai can you share some example how to unpack?

Comment: Use await on your futures. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22900197/scala-how-to-get-the-result-of-a-future

Comment: using await can result in deadlocks . This will not be the solution. Can you please suggest how to merge Future[DataFrame] and return single final DataFrame?

Comment: What is `ProcessSession`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `ProcessSession.apply` itself results in a `Future[DataFrame]`  Depending on how much work is done before you end up with a `Future`, you'll want to:

- if it's a lot of work (thus calling `ProcessSession.apply` in parallel is useful for the extra overhead of creating a promise and scheduling a task in an execution context), you can use the `.flatten` method on a `Future[Future[T]]` to remove one layer of "futurity":

  ```
  for {
    r1 <- future_session.flatten
    r2 <- future_links.flatten
    r3 <- future_nodes.flatten
  } // and so forth
  ```
- If `ProcessSession.apply` doesn't do much before returning a `Future`, then just replace the `Future` blocks with raw `ProcessSession` calls:

  ```
  val future_session = ProcessSession(df, spark)
  val future_links = ProcessSession(df, spark) // Not sure what you really wanted here, but I'm going with what was in the code you posted
  val future_nodes = ProcessSession(df, spark)
  ```